# ASP.NET Core 1 and Entity Framework (Npgsql) breaks Startup class and says: app.UseMvc method not available

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-core

I want to use the Entity Framework 7 in my ASP.NET Core 1 application to connect to a PostgreSQL database.

If I add *EntityFramework.Commands (7.0.0-beta5)* and *EntityFramework7.Npgsql (3.1.0-rc1-3)* to my **project.json** file:

```js
{
  "webroot": "wwwroot",
  "version": "1.0.0-*",

  "dependencies": {

    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-beta5",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.TagHelpers": "6.0.0-beta5",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.Cookies": "1.0.0-beta5",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.Facebook": "1.0.0-beta5",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.Google": "1.0.0-beta5",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.MicrosoftAccount": "1.0.0-beta5",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.Twitter": "1.0.0-beta5",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics": "1.0.0-beta5",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.IIS": "1.0.0-beta5",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener": "1.0.0-beta5",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-beta5",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Tooling.Razor": "1.0.0-beta5",
    "Microsoft.Framework.Configuration.Abstractions": "1.0.0-beta5",
    "Microsoft.Framework.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0-beta5",
    "Microsoft.Framework.Configuration.UserSecrets": "1.0.0-beta5",
    "Microsoft.Framework.Logging": "1.0.0-beta5",
    "Microsoft.Framework.Logging.Console": "1.0.0-beta5",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.Loader": "14.0.0-beta5",

    "EntityFramework.Commands": "7.0.0-beta5",
    "EntityFramework7.Npgsql": "3.1.0-rc1-3"
  },

  "commands": {
    "web": "Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting --config hosting.ini",
    "ef": "EntityFramework.Commands"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "dnx451": { },
    "dnxcore50": { }
  },

  "publishExclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "bower_components",
    "**.xproj",
    "**.user",
    "**.vspscc"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "wwwroot",
    "node_modules",
    "bower_components"
  ]
}
```

I get errors in my Startup.cs

```html
using Microsoft.AspNet.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Framework.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Framework.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Framework.Logging;

namespace Suplim.Web.Platform
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; set; }

        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddMvc();
        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        {
            loggerFactory.MinimumLevel = LogLevel.Information;
            loggerFactory.AddConsole();

            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseBrowserLink();
                app.UseErrorPage(ErrorPageOptions.ShowAll);
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseErrorHandler("/Home/Error");
            }

            app.UseStaticFiles();


            app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Then Visual Studio says that in my **Startup.Configure()** method it can not find the methods:

- app.UseBrowserLink
- app.UseErrorPage
- app.UseErrorHandler
- app.UseStaticFiles
- app.UseMvc

It says

- Core DNX 4.5.1 not available
- Core DNX Core 5 available

But both packages are loaded and available in the Visual Studio references structure (DNX 4.5.1 and DNX Core 5).

If I remove the EntityFramework.Commands and EntityFramework7.Npgsql packages everything works fine.

Why does the Entity Framework affect my Startup class? Are the versions incompatible (beta5 and rc1-final)? If yes what can I do?

I do not understand the problem.

Answer (score 3):

You are using an rc1 package for EF and beta5 for anything else. You can't mix package versions. Move everything to rc1 (beta5 is a thing of the past) and use the rc1 runtime (dnx) otherwise things will break.

Answer (score 0):

I have already tried to set the same version to all packages but some packages are still **beta-*** and others are **rc1-final**. These are the newest packages (I removed the EntityFramework7.Npgsql and other not needed packages for testing):

```html
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.IIS": "1.0.0-beta7",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Tooling.Razor": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Framework.Logging": "1.0.0-beta8",
    "Microsoft.Framework.Logging.Console": "1.0.0-beta8",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.Loader": "14.0.0-rc1-final",

    "EntityFramework.Commands": "7.0.0-rc1-final"
  },
```

And my global.json is now:

```html
{
  "projects": [ "src", "test" ],
  "sdk": {
    "version": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "runtime": "clr",
    "architecture": "x86"
  }
}
```

Now it can not find the **EntityFramework.Commands** and **Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc** packages (both with different version number than 1.0.0) in the **DNX 4.5.1** reference. In the **DNX Core 5** reference it finds nothing, all packages are unresolved.

It is like the old DLL hell ...

Comment: this is not the way of updating u'r question, move it to original post with Edit - Remark  title.

Comment: Also, the logging dlls are in rc1-final.  You may be pointing to the wrong nuget feed.  I would work on getting everything on the same version first then worry about errors.

Comment: Have you checked your nuget feeds?  Make sure you have this one I believe. https://www.myget.org/F/aspnetmaster

Comment: @RickJames I am going to try the aspnetmaster repo tomorrow, thank you. I hope it will solve some problems.

Comment: @maz258: Don't post updates or comments as answers. StackOverflow is not a form, its a Q/A site.

Answer (score 0):

```
"Microsoft.AspNet.Server.IIS": "1.0.0-beta7"
```

needs to be changed to

```
"Microsoft.AspNet.IISPlatformHandler": "1.0.0-rc1-final"
```

As the other responder says you are mixing and matching.  You should have everything on the same version or don't use it.

Comment: Ok, but what is with the Mvc? It is version 6.0.0-rc1-final and is not resolved. Also EntityFramework.Commands and EntityFramework7.Npgsql are in different versions than 1.0.0-rc1-final. I am not able to use them in a 1.0.0-rc1-final? And why nothing is resolved in the DNX Core 5 references? Sorry but it is very confusing, it was much easier in classic ASP.NET MVC 5.

Comment: I know it is still beta but it is very confusing ;-)

Comment: I agree it can be confusing.  Hence though why it is beta.  Everything has changed with each version of beta.  So namespaces have changed etc and that adds to the confusion.  It is the price we pay for using cutting edge.